# Why is this basic program never returning True?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#This programs asks your name, and asks you to guess the characters in it and passes a statement accordingly.  

print ('Hello, what is your first name?') #Asks for first name  
firstName = input()

print ('Hello, what is your second name?') #Asks for second name  
secondName = input()

print ('Guess the number of letters in your first name: ') #Asks for first name letter guess.  
firstLetter = input()

print ('Guess the number of letters in your second name: ') #Asks for second name letter guess  
secondLetter = input()

if len(firstName) == firstLetter and len(secondName) == secondLetter:   
    print ('Corrent! Your name is', firstName, secondName, 'and it has', len(firstName), 'characters in the first name with', len(secondName), 'in the second')

else :  
    print ('Wrong! Your name is', firstName, secondName, 'and it has', len(firstName), 'characters in the first name with', len(secondName), 'in the second')
```

Comment: Because `firstLetter` is a string and `len(firstName)` is an integer.  Ditto for `secondLetter` and `secondName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO and welcome to Python too.

You are trying to compare two different datatypes i.e. `len(firstName)` is an `int` and `firstLetter` is a `str` as you are getting from the user. By default this comparision will return `False`. You can modify the code in two ways to get proper output. Either you have to get the number of characters as int or while comparing you have to convert the datatype as int for `firstLetter` variable.

So the code will look something like,

```
firstLetter = int(input())

if len(firstName) == int(firstLetter) and len(secondName) == int(secondLetter):
    #your code
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!